# EOFError when running python script in background in bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, zsh

So I have a python (using 3.10) file (tests.py) with a prompt that breaks when 'lol' is input.

```
while True:
    msg = input()
    if msg == 'lol':
      break
```

When I run `python3 tests.py &` on the command line, I get the expected output

```
[1] 54951
me@mycomputer current_dir % 
[1]  + suspended (tty input)  python3 tests.py
```

However, when I run a shell file (test.sh) with the same command

```
#!/bin/zsh
python3 tests.py &
```

I get the following output with an EOFError.

```
me@mycomputer current_dir % ./test.sh
me@mycomputer current_dir % Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    msg = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

When I try to handle the EOFError, it either gets stuck in a loop if I use `pass` or `continue`, or it just ends the process if I use `break`. I want the script to behave as if I were running it on the command line.

Is this possible, and could somebody explain what is going on here?

Comment: The difference is that interactive shells implement job control, but shell scripts don't.

Comment: Why are you running the python script with `&`?  What is the purpose?

Comment: How are you planning to send `lol` or other strings to the running script? You may need to redirect the input.